# Community Ads broken (again, 3rd time this year)

Tags: support, advertising

The community ads aren't showing on the main page. It's taken a couple days and multiple people to be sure (per Chernoff I have resisted the urge to sit on my F5 key). Please fix them (again)!

Comment: Yeah, broken here too.  Seems like they break when the set of "real" ads changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have worked with Chernoff a few times on getting these ads fixed :) I just pulled a report for the impressions served over the last week- the open source ads served over 3000 impressions, so they're not broken, they just have a low Share of Voice (SOV). I will increase the SOV and ask that you keep me posted.

Comment: Ah; if they're working no need to mess with it (SOV or otherwise). I know there's a couple campaigns that are on the blitz right now, so I imaging they'd displace the community ads for the most part. Just seems like they weren't working.